# How can I compare the values of an Iterable

Tags: java, iterable

Let's say I have a list if I want to compare all the values> I would do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = (i+1); j < list.size(); j++) {

    }
}
```

This way all values are compared one time and not two. Is there a way to execute a similar comparing if my values are returned as an Iterable?

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding your question. Can you please better explain it?

Comment: Transform the Iterable to a List, and use the same algorithm.

Comment: he want to use an iterator but want to start at a certain item of this iterator.

Comment: To compare use comparator

Comment: you cannot copy java.util.iterator, so you should do this with the way that you've shown in your question.

Comment: Which is your goal here? It does not sound conceptually right what you are trying to achieve, but I did not really understand your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You could use an Iterable for the outer loop, but not for the inner. And for what you're doing, you want to work on the same collection for inner and outer loops. So you need to work with a List here.

You should probably explain what you want to achieve by comparing all elements in the list. If you want to sort the list, for example, that's not the right way to do it.